# linear-gradient syntax unclear

Tags: css, sass, linear-gradients

I am trying to understand this [pen](https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/OJNLyOv), but I have difficulties understanding line 44-45 in the SCSS file:

`background: linear-gradient(var(--menu-link-active-color) 0 100%) left / 0 repeat;`

I looked up many websites, but I couldn't find anything about `linear-gradient()` with 3 parameters. And also the slash is very unclear. I would be happy to get a hint or an explanation what this is!

Comment: The first search result for "CSS linear gradient" shows how it can have many parameters and how to use them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()

Comment: That same site has good documentation on how to use the slash in the `background` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: @Sean can you explain his case using the links you shared? The syntax is the question is not a conventional one and you will rarely find it inside documentation so it's not easy to understand even if you have the documentation

Comment: I actually searched the web for at least one hour. It might have been more. I have already checked the docs of this property and tried to change the css of the pen, however, I was definitely not able to understand the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such gradient means a solid color placed at left with a size equal to `0`. `0` is equivalent to `0 auto` and `auto` will default to `100%`. So a gradient having `0` width and `100%` height.

The 3 parameter is a color having 2 color stops. `red 0 100%` means a gradient having `red` at `0` and `red` at `100%`. You can also use `red 0 0`.

Here is an example to better understand. The background will go from 0 to 100%

```css
.box {
 background: 
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) 
   left / 
   0  
   no-repeat;
  height:100px;
  transition:.5s;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

An easier syntax would be:

```css
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands this:

```
background: linear-gradient(var(--menu-link-active-color) 0 100%) left / 0 repeat;
```

does nothing.

That is because the 3 parameters (actually, it's no-repeat in the codepen but that makes not difference to this linear-gradient) after the background-image (the linear-gradient) are:

position - left - self explanatory and actually corresponding to the default of 0

after the / is size and it's 0 i.e. the element has no size

repeat (or no-repeat)

Now, why bother you ask?

Well, the reason is because of the hover. When the user hovers the size is changed (using a CSS calculation) so that color (shown as an image by the linear gradient) expands all the way across the associated word.

Notice also that the color itself is given by a CSS variable, and that can change for each word or the state.